# How to store user interests in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site using Php/MySQL and my question is quite simple (I hope). During the registration process, a user is asked to select their interests from a list of about 15. What would be the best way to store these in the database against each user? Should I store the interests in a separate table and have a join table to match the user_id to the interest_id?

Comment: If a user can have many interests and an interest can belong to many users then yes, make an intersection table

Comment: I disagree with the mods that it is too broad and that there are too many possible answers. Proof: all of the answers here are offering the exact same thing.

Comment: I disagree too - It's not a broad question considering the answers are all very similar. Whatever the case - I know now how to do something I wasn't too sure about before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have a `Users` table and an `Interests` table with no duplicates.

And then, you should have a mapping table to map Users to their Interests, perhaps called `UserInterests`.

Make sure when you create your mapping table that you make the **primary key(user_id, interest_id)** and that they are also both **foreign keys**.

### UPDATE

Here is a link to a sqlFiddle where you can run some queries against our proposed schema.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f500a8/6

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for taking the time to put together an example @ChrisLava

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's best to keep the database [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), making it easier to query against common information (ie, get all the users who have this interest).

You could have a `interests` table with the interests:

```
| iID | iInterest |
| 1   | Cars      |
| 2   | Computers |
```

Then, for instance, your users table:

```
| uID | uName |
| 1   | John  |
| 2   | Jake  |
```

Then you would have a many to many relationship table that links the users to the interests (UserInterests):

```
| uID | iID |
| 1   | 1   |
| 1   | 2   |
| 2   | 2   |
```

From this, you can see that user John likes cars and computers, but user Jake only likes computers.  Say you want to get all the users that like computers, all you have to do is join the tables together:

```
SELECT uName 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN UserInterests ON Users.uID = UserInterests.uID 
AND UserInterests.uID = 2
```

Comment: _"error, dubble entry on 'uid'"_ at the UserInterests-table. How to prevent this message while uid is a foreign key?

Comment: Do you have the primary key for the UserInterests table to include both the uID and iID columns?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I store the interests in a separate table and have a join table to match the user_id to the interest_id?

Yes. It's called a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) and can ensure that there no duplication of the interests themselves, allows the user to have multiple interests and uses a numeric key (which is faster than alphanumeric keys).

Adapted from the wiki article:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    UserPassword VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UserName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Interests (
    InterestId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    InterestDescription VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
)

-- This is the junction table.
CREATE TABLE UserInterests (
    UserId INTEGER REFERENCES Users (UserId),
    InterestId INTEGER REFERENCES Interests (InterestKey),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId, InterestKey)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a many-to-many relationship: create a table `Person` and `Interest` and then a `PersonInterest` that joins the ids of each table.